# Skip values from a list wrapped within quotation marks

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro to get the individual value from a list. My intention is to skip those values wrapped with quotation marks. How can I do so?

I've written so far:

```
Sub dosth()
    Dim post As Variant

    For Each post In [{"1","'2'","3","'4'"}]
        Debug.Print post
    Next post
End Sub
```

Result it produces:

```
1
'2'
3
'4'
```

What I wish to have:

```
1
3
```

Can't find any idea to apply any conditional logic here. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use a simple condition If Left(post, 1) <> "'" Then Debug.Print post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a test of the ascii value. 39 is `'`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dosth()
    Dim elements As Variant, post As Variant
    elements = [{"1","'2'","3","'4'"}]
    For Each post In elements
        If AscW(post) <> 39 Then Debug.Print post
    Next post
End Sub
```

Similar idea

```
Option Explicit
Sub dosth()
    Dim elements As Variant, post As Variant
    elements = [{"1","'2'","3","'4'"}]
    For Each post In elements
        If Not Left$(post, 1) = Chr$(39) Then Debug.Print post
    Next post
End Sub
```

Comment: You are incredible. Accept it when time is right. Btw, what is `"` connected to?

Comment: you want to know what the code is for that? " is chr$(34)